# why my tasks is skipping when i run ansible playbook

Tags: ansible-tower

```yaml
- name: get user list from centOs
            ansible.builtin.shell:
                    cmd: cat /etc/passwd
            when: ansible_distribution == "CentOs"
            register: command_output
          - debug:
                  var: command_output.stdout_lines
```

When I run this playbook it shows like this

```
TASK [get user list from centOs] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: []

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [] => {
    "command_output.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is skipped because you specified:

```
when: ansible_distribution == "CentOs"
```

This must be a typo. There is no distribution `"CentOs"` defined. There is a distribution `"CentOS"`. Try that instead.